# Problems in debugging IAR Embedded Workshop

Tags: debugging, iar, stm8

I have received some code which I have to maintain. To do this I will be using IAR embedded workbench. 
Since it is my first time I am watching some tutorials like
[Getting Started with IAR Embedded Workbench](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-C2MjbJXAyw)

Now if you look at minute 4.32, you can see that there are *two* green lines. One in the code area and one in the disassembly area. You can go between one and the other

In my case there is only *one!* green line (in the disassembly area) and no matter what you do you can not go to the code area. You can not set breakpoints either (well you can but when you run the program they are deactivated)

I don't think this can be find in the getting started guides so I am asking the help of someone experienced in IAR

Why would this be happening and how can I debug my program?

Thanks for any comment help or idea

Comment: Do you have optimizations on (compiler settings) and have you included debug information (linker settings)?

Comment: I would suggest doing a clean and rebuild of your project. It sounds like IAR doesn't have the proper link between disassembly and your source files. I've seen this happen if projects are moved or copied to a new location without a clean and rebuild.

Comment: This would happen if there is no debug info in the compiled code, or if the debugger fails to find the source files. Do you have any source code in the disassembly window?

Answer (score 1):

The following solved this issue for me after hours of searching myself:

https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless-connectivity/sub-1-ghz/f/156/t/192852?Why-IAR-reports-can-not-run-to-main-or-failed-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-main-

Hope no one else gets stuck with this one